# Ninject Error using configuration manager while registering. This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase

Tags: c#, web-config, ninject, configurationmanager

I have a C# 4.0 Mvc 4 web application that uses Ninject.  Everything has been registering fine, but when i try to access values from my Web.config section using configurationmanager class i get this error: "An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for apiUserGroup/apiUser: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.".  I can access app settings, and connection strings, but not configuration sections.  The section has been used for a while, so I know it is not a config setup issue.  Any ideas?

Config:

```
     <configSections>

   <sectionGroup name="apiUserGroup">
      <section name="apiUser" type="JobTracker.Code.ApiUserSection" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>

  <apiUserGroup>
    <apiUser userName="XXXX" passWord="XXXX" role="API" />
  </apiUserGroup>
```

Code to access values:

```
ConfigurationManager.GetSection("apiUserGroup/apiUser") as ApiUserSection;
```

Full Stack Trace (not a very full one):

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for apiUserGroup/apiUser: This method cannot be called during the application's pre-start initialization phase.

ApiUserSection looks like this:

```
public class ApiUserSection : ConfigurationSection
{
    [ConfigurationProperty("userName", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = true)]
    public string UserName
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["userName"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["userName"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("passWord", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = true)]
    public string PassWord
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["passWord"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["passWord"] = value;
        }
    }

    [ConfigurationProperty("role", DefaultValue = "false", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Role
    {
        get
        {
            return (string)this["role"];
        }
        set
        {
            this["role"] = value;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you post your web.config? Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace?

Comment: Where in your MVC project is this function invoked?

Comment: It is invoked in my NinjectWebCommon where i am registering my interfaces.  I get this object so that i can use the api key and username as constructor params to my http client.

Comment: What happens when you set this in your appsettings? `<add key="enableSimpleMembership" value="false"/>
<add key="autoFormsAuthentication" value="false"/>`

Comment: Nothing, i read about that and tried it but it doesnt change anything.  I think that has more to do with upgrading to mvc 4 and the sql membership provider.  I can read from appsettings however, so a workaround for this is to loose the section and just add two app settings, i am just confused as to why sections don't work.

Comment: Is config sections the first thing in the web.config? What happens when you change type to "JobTracker.Code.ApiUserSection, ApiUserSection"?

Comment: What does ApiUserSection look like?

Comment: as for adding the ", ApiUserSection", it didnt change anything.

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap your call to `ConfigurationManager.GetSection()`
in a `Func` and pass that as your constructor argument thereby deferring execution until after the application has initialised, like so:

```
Func<ApiUserSection> apiUserSection = () =>
  {
    return ConfigurationManager.GetSection("apiUserGroup/apiUser") as ApiUserSection;
  };

kernel.Bind<YourHttpClient>().ToSelf()
  .WithConstructorArgument("apiUserSettings", apiUserSection);
```

In the `YourHttpClient` constructor:

```
public YourHttpClient(Func<ApiUserSection> apiUserSettings)
{
  var userSettings = apiUserSettings();
  //...
}
```